# PHP class return nothing

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm just beginner with PHP OOP. I have a class and output is empty:

```
$test = new form('name1', 'passw2');
         $test->getName();
```

and class:

```
<?php
class form
{
    protected $username;
    protected $password;
    protected $errors = array();

    function _construct($username, $password){
        $this->username=$username;
        $this->password=$password;
    }

    public function getsomething() {
       echo '<br>working'. $this->getn() . '<-missed';
    }

    public function getName(){

    return $this->getsomething();   

    }   
    public function getn() {
        return $this->username;
    }
}
?>
```

And output is only text without username: 
POST working 
working<-missed
Where is name1?

Comment: 1) `_construct` needs 2 underscores 2) return in `getName()` is pretty useless, since you just return the return value of `getsomething()` and that function does just return NULL.

Comment: @Rizier123 how i just said this is a trail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modifed your code a bit and added some examples to play around with.
This should get you started.

```
class form
{
    protected $username;
    protected $password;
    protected $errors = array();

    // construct is a magic function, two underscores are needed here

    function __construct($username, $password){
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    // functions starting with get are called Getters
    // they are accessor functions for the class property of the same name

    public function getPassword(){
        return $this->password;
    }  

    public function getUserName() {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function render() {
       echo '<br>working:';
       echo '<br>Name: ' . $this->username;     // using properties directly
       echo '<br>Password:' . $this->password;  // not the getters 
    }
}
```

---

```
$test = new form('name1', 'passw2');

// output via property access
echo $test->username;
echo $test->password;

// output via getter methods
echo $test->getUserName();
echo $test->getPassword();

// output via the render function of the class
$test->render();
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi You have used `_construct` it should be `__contrust(2 underscores)`